# Show that this field is finite and count its elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I want to show that $\Bbb Z[i]/(2+3i)$ is a finite field and count it's elements.

I don't really know how to show that this field is finite.  I start by trying to understand that definition of this ring, so I write

$\Bbb Z[i]/(2+3i)=${$a+bi+2+3i:a,b \in \Bbb Z$}

I don't really know what to do from here. The knowledge needed to solve this shouldn't be much farther than the Chinese Remainder theorem, so I think it should be relatively simple but I don't see how to approach it.  Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: You say "the Chinese Remainder Theorem," but there are many forms of this theorem. To which do you refer?

Comment: It may be that you will find this helpful: note that $(2+3i)(2-3i)=13$, so that $(2+3i)|13$ and consequently $(2+3i)\supset(13)$. This means, in turn, that there is a surjective homomorphism of rings, $\Bbb Z[i]/(13)\to\Bbb Z[i]/(2+3i)$.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few hints:

1. In this ring, $2+3i = 0$.  That means that any time you encounter $3i$ you can replace it with $-2$.  Using this technique you can rewrite any element in the form $a+bi$ where $b$ is either $0$, $1$, or $2$.
2. Also, since $2+3i = 0$ in this ring, we also have $4+6i=0$.  But also we have $(2+3i)^2=0$.  Combining those identities you should be able to find a positive integer $n$ with the property that $n=0$ in this ring.

Answer (score 2):

Your "definition of the ring" is already wrong, which is why you're not understanding it at all. $\{ a+bi+2+3i : a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \}$ is exactly the same as $\{ a+bi : a,b\in\mathbb{Z} \}$! Whenever you form equivalence classes, each element is a **class** of elements that are equivalent under the equivalence relation, which in this case is modulo $(2+3i)$. Once you get that right, it should be obvious why there are only finitely many equivalence classes of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ mod $(2+3i)$.

Comment: Good point on showing that it's equivalent to that definition which is nonsensical!  So I'm modulating by (2+3i), so it should be a+bi (mod 2+3i), is that it?  Then it's obvious, it's like showing $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ is a finite field?

Comment: @Jeff Don't forget that you have to show it's a field, not just that it's finite.

Comment: Yes but once the elements are counted showing its a field is relatively simple, I think understanding the concept of it was the important part, thank you

Comment: @Jeff: Sort of. In general it would be best to fully understand the concept of equivalence classes. The quotient ring you are talking about here is $\{ \{ x+(2+3i)y \} : x,y \in \mathbb{Z}[i] \}$. You can see that any equivalence class containing $x$ contains all the elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ that are equivalent to $x$ mod $(2+3i)$.